# In Excel how do you make the number in one cell change the date in another?

Tags: excel

I wanted the input of one value to change the date in another cell, for blood test results and date of retesting so for instance if the value is below 60 then change the date to six months from today otherwise change to three months from today or if higher then 60 then one year.

Comment: If you want that date to remain static after the cell is updated(not change every day after) then you will need vba in a Worksheet change event.

Comment: No VBA necessary, =if(testresult<60,today()+180,what you want to do if value is >=60) - assuming i understand the question.

Comment: @TimNevins but that date will change tomorrow.  the point is that if the op wants to look at the return date next week for that patient the date will need to be static. `TODAY()` is volatile and just opening the workbook the date will change.  So no a formula will not work.

Comment: I knew I was missing something. Do the records not have a date associated with them that can be used for the calculation?

Comment: Hey, do need a static date and will be adding the date initially in one cell with a value then it will take that value and add a second date in a different cell so over 60 +365, 30-60 +180 and less than 30 +90.  hope that makes sense